# How to change TypeFace from BOLD to NORMAL once data updated on recyclerview adapter?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I'm working with Firebase data and `RecyclerView` `Adapter`.

The scenario is when user click the list, the initial status was `UNREAD` will be change to `READ` so the `TypeFace` should be change from `BOLD` to `NORMAL`.

My current back-end process to change the status from `UNREAD` to `READ` is working and updated to Firebase, however the interface of my specific `RecyclerView` item does not change from `BOLD` to `NORMAL`.

What I thought is no need to recall back the ***Firebase data*** in order to read the status but the interface should change based on user click.

***Anyone can help me?***

---

***`NotificationActivity.java`***:

```
package com.myapp.activity.notification;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.view.ActionMode;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.material.nereeducation.R;
import com.material.nereeducation.adapter.AdapterNotification;
import com.material.nereeducation.model.Notification;
import com.material.nereeducation.utils.Tools;
import com.material.nereeducation.widget.LineItemDecoration;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class NotificationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private AdapterNotification mAdapter;
    private ActionModeCallback actionModeCallback;
    private ActionMode actionMode;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification);

        initToolbar();
        initComponent();
        Tools.setSystemBarColor(this, R.color.black);
    }

    private void initToolbar() {
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Notifications");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    private List<Notification> items = new ArrayList<>();
    private LinearLayout messageEmptyList;
    private void initComponent() {

        messageEmptyList = findViewById(R.id.messageEmptyList);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new LineItemDecoration(this, LinearLayout.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        //set data and list adapter
        mAdapter = new AdapterNotification(this, items);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter.setOnClickListener(new AdapterNotification.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, Notification obj, int pos) {
                if (mAdapter.getSelectedItemCount() > 0) {
                    enableActionMode(pos);
                } else {
                    // read the inbox which removes bold from the row
                    Notification notification = mAdapter.getItem(pos);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Read: " + notification.sender_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    updateStatus(notification.notificationId,"read",pos);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemLongClick(View view, Notification obj, int pos) {
                enableActionMode(pos);
            }
        });

        actionModeCallback = new ActionModeCallback();

        getNotificationData();

    }

    private void getNotificationData()
    {
        items.clear();
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        final Gson gson = builder.create();

        FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        String uuid = firebaseAuth.getUid();

        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();

        databaseReference.child("notifications/"+uuid+"/data_notification").orderByChild("status").startAt("read").endAt("unread").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.getValue() != null)
                {
                    for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        String dataReceived = gson.toJson(snapshot.getValue());
                        Notification notificationItems = gson.fromJson(dataReceived, Notification.class);
                        items.add(notificationItems);
                    }
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else
                {
                    messageEmptyList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void updateStatus(final String notificationId, String status, final int position) {
        FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        String uuid = firebaseAuth.getUid();

        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();

        databaseReference.child("notifications/"+uuid+"/data_notification").child(notificationId).child("status").setValue(status
        ).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position); //Problem here - how to update text from BOLD to NORMAL for this item?
            }
        });
    }

    private void enableActionMode(int position) {
        if (actionMode == null) {
            actionMode = startSupportActionMode(actionModeCallback);
        }
        toggleSelection(position);
    }

    private void toggleSelection(int position) {
        mAdapter.toggleSelection(position);
        int count = mAdapter.getSelectedItemCount();

        if (count == 0) {
            actionMode.finish();
        } else {
            actionMode.setTitle(String.valueOf(count));
            actionMode.invalidate();
        }
    }

    private class ActionModeCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_delete, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_delete) {
                deleteInboxes();
                mode.finish();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            mAdapter.clearSelections();
            actionMode = null;
        }
    }

    private void deleteInboxes() {
        List<Integer> selectedItemPositions = mAdapter.getSelectedItems();
        for (int i = selectedItemPositions.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            mAdapter.removeData(selectedItemPositions.get(i));
        }
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            finish();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

***`AdapterNotification.java`***:

```
package com.myapp.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.format.DateUtils;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.material.nereeducation.R;
import com.material.nereeducation.helper.AlphabetColor;
import com.material.nereeducation.model.Notification;
import com.material.nereeducation.utils.Tools;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class AdapterNotification extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterNotification.ViewHolder> {

    private Context ctx;
    private List<Notification> items;
    private OnClickListener onClickListener = null;

    private SparseBooleanArray selected_items;
    private int current_selected_idx = -1;

    private AlphabetColor alphabetColor;

    public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener onClickListener) {
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView from, title, message, date, image_letter;
        public ImageView image;
        public RelativeLayout lyt_checked, lyt_image;
        public View lyt_parent;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            from = view.findViewById(R.id.from);
            title = view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            message = view.findViewById(R.id.message);
            date = view.findViewById(R.id.date);
            image_letter = view.findViewById(R.id.image_letter);
            image = view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            lyt_checked = view.findViewById(R.id.lyt_checked);
            lyt_image = view.findViewById(R.id.lyt_image);
            lyt_parent = view.findViewById(R.id.lyt_parent);
        }
    }

    public AdapterNotification(Context mContext, List<Notification> items) {
        this.ctx = mContext;
        this.items = items;
        selected_items = new SparseBooleanArray();
        alphabetColor = new AlphabetColor(mContext);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_notification, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Notification notification = items.get(position);

        // displaying text view data

        System.out.println("sender type:"+notification.sender_type);
        Character firstLetter;
        if(notification.sender_type.equals("1")) //Admin
        {
            String admin = ctx.getString(R.string.admin_name);
            holder.from.setText(admin);
            firstLetter = admin.substring(0, 1).charAt(0);

            holder.image_letter.setText(String.valueOf(firstLetter));
        }else
        {
            holder.from.setText(notification.senderName);
            firstLetter = notification.senderName.substring(0, 1).charAt(0);
            holder.image_letter.setText(String.valueOf(firstLetter));
        }
        if(notification.status.equals("unread"))
        {
            holder.from.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));
            holder.title.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));
        }

        holder.title.setText(notification.title);
        holder.message.setText(notification.message);
        holder.date.setText(getDate(Long.parseLong(notification.date)));

        holder.lyt_parent.setActivated(selected_items.get(position, false));

        holder.lyt_parent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (onClickListener == null) return;
                onClickListener.onItemClick(v, notification, position);
            }
        });

        holder.lyt_parent.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                if (onClickListener == null) return false;
                onClickListener.onItemLongClick(v, notification, position);
                return true;
            }
        });

        toggleCheckedIcon(holder, position);
        displayImage(holder, notification, firstLetter);

    }

    private void displayImage(ViewHolder holder, Notification notification, Character firstLetter) {
        if (notification.image != null) {
            Tools.displayImageRound(ctx, holder.image, notification.image);
            holder.image.setColorFilter(null);
            holder.image_letter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.shape_circle);
            holder.image.setColorFilter(alphabetColor.getColorByAlphabet(firstLetter), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            holder.image_letter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private String getDate(long time) {
        Date date = new Date();
        long currentTime = date.getTime();
        String result = (String) DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(time, currentTime, 0);
        return result;
    }



    private void toggleCheckedIcon(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (selected_items.get(position, false)) {
            holder.lyt_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.lyt_checked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (current_selected_idx == position) resetCurrentIndex();
        } else {
            holder.lyt_checked.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.lyt_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (current_selected_idx == position) resetCurrentIndex();
        }
    }

    public Notification getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public void toggleSelection(int pos) {
        current_selected_idx = pos;
        if (selected_items.get(pos, false)) {
            selected_items.delete(pos);
        } else {
            selected_items.put(pos, true);
        }
        notifyItemChanged(pos);
    }

    public void clearSelections() {
        selected_items.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getSelectedItemCount() {
        return selected_items.size();
    }

    public List<Integer> getSelectedItems() {
        List<Integer> items = new ArrayList<>(selected_items.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < selected_items.size(); i++) {
            items.add(selected_items.keyAt(i));
        }
        return items;
    }

    public void removeData(int position) {
        items.remove(position);
        resetCurrentIndex();


    }

    private void resetCurrentIndex() {
        current_selected_idx = -1;
    }

    public interface OnClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, Notification obj, int pos);

        void onItemLongClick(View view, Notification obj, int pos);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle ELSE too for this condition

```
if(notification.status.equals("unread")){
   holder.from.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));
   holder.title.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));
}else{
   holder.from.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.NORMAL));
   holder.title.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.NORMAL));
}
```

Comment: The result still the same... What I meant is after data changed, BOLD still not change to NORMAL

Comment: are you sure you already update the new value to the adapter?

 mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);

Seems like you just told the adapter to refresh with the old data.

Comment: you need to update the notification.status for that row first, then called 

mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set textview different typeface or color in adapter you need to check for every position so in your case you only setting typeface bold for textview you have to set typeface again normal for default textview typeface.

Set your typeface Normal also in adapter.

set text default typeface Normal for textview like below.

```
holder.from.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.NORMAL));
   holder.title.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.NORMAL));
```

and then check item status for unread

```
   if(notification.status.equals("unread")){
       holder.from.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));
       holder.title.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));
    }
```

Comment: No changes, what I meant is after data changed, BOLD still not change to NORMAL... how to directly change only that item instead of using `item.clear()` ?

Comment: whats the need of item.clear(); you can refersh single position using just set adapter.notifyItemChanged(int position)

Comment: I tried, the item did refresh. But the style still the same. I think the old data called did not update. How it can be set like `text.setText("New data")` for that item only after method `updateStatus()` called?

Comment: i think your data refreshing but problem is you are not updating your arrraylist position ,you have to update particular position also to reflect the data.Do one thing print the value of notification.status of that particular position after refersh data you will get some idea wherers the actual problem

Answer (score 0):

So I guess your problem is that the state (read/unread) is applied on the database, but not reflected on the recycler view.

If this is the problem it is mainly because, you didnt handle the data change method of your list (and update it with the new values).

You are currently using this to get data:

```
       databaseReference.child("notifications/"+uuid+"/data_notification").orderByChild("status").startAt("read").endAt("unread").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {.....
```

This won't help you to control the item changed too.

**Possible solution**

A way solve it is to use (FirebaseUI) database instead of custom adapter.

FirebaseUI will listen to changes and update the list.

**EDIT 2**

use ChildEventListener instead of Listener For Single Value event

instead of this:

```
     databaseReference.child("notifications/"+uuid+"/data_notification").orderByChild("status").startAt("read").endAt("unread").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {.....
```

use this:

```
     databaseReference.child("notifications/"+uuid+"/data_notification").orderByChild("status").startAt("read").endAt("unread").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {.....


        //add items to list (like you did)



         @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {.....

        //set the items again to the list (update them here) and notify
        //data set changed (so values update in your list).
```

Comment: How to use FirebaseUI? Can we just focus on recyclerview?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should set the font like this:

```
if ("unread".equals(notification.status)) {
    holder.from.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    holder.title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
} else {
    holder.from.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
    holder.title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
}
```

The view is being reused by `RecyclerView` so once you set font to bold you need to set it back to normal next time it will be used.